# Leave cell blank until data entered

Tags: excel, date, time, formula, cell

I would like for the totals to show nothing until data on left is entered (see image.)  I have tried many formula's using the IF, ISBLANK, OR, and NA functions.  Nothing seems to be working. I could also use help with the "Total Time," as well.

[image: Excel Relief Timekeeping Record]

Comment: `=IF(OR(F10="",D10=""),"",yourformula)`.

Comment: Thank you!! That worked.  Wish I would've asked for help sooner. :D

Comment: You add your existing formula (minus the beginning `=`), where it says `yourformula`?